# Is it possible to encrypt the notify_url field in a paypal form?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

It seem it isn't.  My encrypted buttons work fine, but if I add the notify_url in to the encryption I get an error, it only appears to work if I set it as a standard hidden field.

I know I can set a notify_url in my paypal account (and indeed that's what I've relied on for years), but I can't be the only person that desires for different purchases from different websites to be handled by different scripts!

Is there a solution that doesn't involve laying my notify_url bare for the whole world to see?

Am I worrying about nothing?  Is it fine to have this URL publicly viewable..?

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are valid.

1. Displaying a push notification url is a potential security hole if it contains api keys (e.g. http://example.com/push?secret_key=abc123&public_key=notsosecret).
2. If this is strictly the url with no encryption or api keys (e.g. http://example.com/push) it's not a problem as someone is going to find that url eventually anyway and it should be secured with a manner other than obscurity.

Why does this data have to be available client side either way? Can't you attach it server side after form submission but before sending the data?

Answer (score 0):

The URL cannot be encrypted, but the request made to it by PayPal can (and, in fact, **must**) be verified by your application.

For details on how to verify a request, see the [PayPal IPN Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). In short, though, the request to your notification URL will contain some information which you can send back to a PayPal server to confirm to confirm for yourself that it was really sent by PayPal, and to let PayPal know that you received the notification.

(If you do not confirm an incoming notification, PayPal will repeat the notification several times, so it's critical that you follow this procedure!)